# OpenCL histogram with many bins

Tags: opencl, gpu, histogram

I am using the code presented in Chapter 14 of the OpenCL Progamming Guide to calculate a histogram. It works fine for 256 bins, but unfortunately I need 65536 bins for my application. This leads to the problem that if I use this approach, the local array gets too big.

```
local uint tmp_histogram[256 * 256];
```

As a result, the program is not built (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE).

Do you have any ideas how this issue can be solved? I thought of using multiple kernels to compute the values for the different bins (i.e. to split the histogram, so that I first compute the values for the bins 0-255, then for 256-511, etc.). However, in this case I will have to check if a value is within that range before incrementing, which means that I will need conditionals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global memory would solve the problem, but would not result in a very fast kernel. I suggest creating multiple work groups, and using each group to count a range of values only.

```
#define RANGE_SIZE 8192

kernel void histo(__global uint data,__constant int dataSize){
    int wid = get_local_id(0);
    int wSize = get_local_size(0);

    int gid = get_group_id(0);
    int numGroups = get_num_groups(0);

    int rangeStart = gid * RANGE_SIZE / numGroups;
    int rangeEnd = (gid+1) * RANGE_SIZE / numGroups;

    local uint tmp_histogram[RANGE_SIZE];

    uint value;

    for(int i=wid; i< dataSize; i+= wSize){
        value = data[i];
        if(value >= rangeStart && value < rangeEnd){
            atomic_inc(tmp_histogram[value - rangeStart]);
        }
    }
    //barrier...
    //use the local data here
}
```

Assumes 32kb local memory available. If you reduce RANGE_SIZE, it does not have to be a power of two, but you do need to make sure you are calling the kernel with enough work groups to hit all values up to 64k.

Comment: I agree with this approach. Minor nitpick: the local memory requirements are `sizeof(uint)*RANGE_SIZE`, so your snippet actually requires 128Kb at the moment.

Comment: Exactly right. That is the calculation to minimize the number of work groups. You also want to have as few groups as possible, because each group is essentially skipping a bunch of values for the histogram. I corrected the 'x' / 'value mistake in the code.

Comment: I deleted my comment before I saw yours, because I found that some points were not correct. The local size should not be determined as "available local memory/ (RANGE_SIZE*sizeof(int))", because the local memory is shared by all work-items in the group and I need only one tmp_histogram array for the whole group. Instead of this the local size could be chosen experimentally depending on whether the synchronization of the work-items or the sequental part (the for loop) is time-consuming. One more remark - when you calculate rangeStart and rangeEnd, you don't need to divide by numGroups.

Comment: Isn't the required local memory 256Kb with RANGE_SIZE equal to 8192? According to jprice's comment RANGE_SIZE should be 1024, right?

Comment: The original value I had wrote was 32768. 8192 is the correct value, because local uint tmp_histogram[RANGE_SIZE] requires 32kb of local memory. The value can be changed for platforms with different amounts of local memory.

Answer (score 1):

Move your histogram to global storage. 
A further solution could be to use unsigned short,  if your application suits this size. 
At last you could run your code twice.  first time for lower 32000 values,  second time for the upper half.

Comment: I think I won't improve the performance if I move the histogram to global memory, but using unsigned short is definetely a good idea for appropriate data.